# How to get date from mongodb matched date using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to return the matching records for a given date query using mongodb and mongoose, however, all rows are returning.

Below is my code and model schema. `todaydate` is of type Date.

Mongodb Data:

```
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5edd1df67b272e2d4cf36f70"),
pname:"Test 1", 
category:"Choco 1",
todaydate:2020-06-01T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5gdd1df67b272e2d4cf36f72"),
pname:"Test 2", 
category:"Choco 3",
todaydate: 2020-06-02T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5kdd1df67b272e2d4cf36f74"),
pname:"Test 5", 
category:"Choco 6",
todaydate: 2020-05-01T18:30:00.000+00:00
},
{ 
_id:ObjectId("5ewd1df67b272e2d4cf36f75"),
pname:"Test 6", 
category:"Choco 8",
todaydate: 2020-06-03T18:30:00.000+00:00
}
```

data.model.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var userSchemaDate = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    pname: {
        type: String
    },  
    category: {
        type: String
    },  
    todaydate: {
        type: Date
    }   
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    collection: 'data'
}); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', userSchemaDate);
```

data.controller.js:

```
module.exports.getReportTableData = (req, res, next) => {
    var collection = req.query.collection;  
    let tabledata = dbc.model(collection);  
    let reportPar = new Date("2020-06-03"); //yyyy-mm-dd
        tabledata.find({
            todaydate: {
                $gte: reportPar
            }
        }, function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("Successful loaded data");
                res.json({ data: docs, msg: 'Data loaded.' });
            }
        }); 
     }
```

Comment: Is there an error or are you not getting the expected rows returned?

Comment: @SamuelG: All records are coming

Comment: can you share the schema definition for that column

Comment: @SamuelG:Added schema model

Comment: all looks fine in your demo. if the data wasn't actually saved as date within MongoDB then you would get no results. there must be something else. check the correct route is being hit etc.

Comment: @SamuelG: Data actually saved as date within MongoDB.but i am getting all records

Comment: @SamuelG:   timezone issue?

Comment: I thought so, but `Date("2020-06-03")` would still have covered `2020-06-03T18:30:00.000+00:00` - can you quickly add some data that is well prior to your search criteria - like a month in the past and see if you still get all rows

Comment: @SamuelG:I have added more rows but still getting all rows

Comment: @SamuelG : Please tell me or give me sample code, How to define schema model for todayday
and How to insert date value for todaydate (Date format) and How to get the documents matched date
and How to get documents matched between the two dates

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes..Resolved...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see anything in your example that stands out as problematic--assuming your system clocks are not totally off.

For reference, here is a snippet to review for comparison to your code:

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/tests`, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, autoIndex: false});
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
});

db.once('open', async () => {
    // wipe the table
    const collections = await db.db.collections();
    if (collections.map(c => c.s.namespace.collection).includes('datetests')) {
        await db.db.collection('datetests').drop();
    }

    // define schema
    const schema = new Schema(
        {
            todaydate: {
                type: Date,
                required: true
            }
        },
        {
            versionKey: false,
            timestamps: false
        }
    );

    const Test = mongoose.model('datetest', schema);

    // insert a week's dates
    let start = new Date('2020-06-02');
    for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        const date = new Date(start.valueOf());
        date.setDate(start.getDate() + i);

        await Test.create({
            todaydate: date
        });
    }

    let result = await Test.find({
        todaydate: {
            $gte: new Date('2020-06-02'), $lte: new Date('2020-06-02')
        }
    }).exec();

    assert.ok(result.length === 1);

    result = await Test.find({
        todaydate: {
            $gte: new Date('2020-06-02'), $lte: new Date('2020-06-03')
        }
    }).exec();

    assert.ok(result.length === 2);

    result = await Test.find({
        todaydate: {
            $gte: new Date('2020-06-02'), $lte: new Date('2020-06-05')
        }
    }).exec();

    assert.ok(result.length === 4);

    result = await Test.find({
        todaydate: {
            $gte: new Date('2020-06-02'), $lte: new Date('2020-06-08')
        }
    }).exec();

    assert.ok(result.length === 7);
});
```